# What configuration should I use for TFS 2010 on my WHS machine?

Tags: sql-server, windows-home-server, team-foundation-server

I would like to perform a fresh install of TFS 2010 on my HP MediaSmart Server EX 490. The EX 490 has a 900 GB drive with a 20 GB partition for the OS. I have added two additional 1.5 TB drives extending the storage space. This balances those two drives and the D:\ partition of the first drive across as one volume.

This article ([Installing Team Foundation Server 2010 on Windows Home Server](http://richhewlett.com/2010/07/09/installing-team-foundation-server-2010-on-windows-home-server/))

seems to indicate that I should not have included both drives as storage hard drives, but rather have one separate for the SQL Server Express 2008 database.

I am incline to just put the database in D:\, which is magically across these three drives, by installing SQL Server Express first. Is this a good approach? Finally how do I install anything, given that I have ISO files to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server data files are best put on their own drive.  Due to the large number of reads and writes this may overwhelm WHS drive extender.  Your second question about ISO files...these are image files that need to be burnt to a DVD (not copied).

Since you have TFS2010 I assume you have an MSDN subscription.  I'd suggest installing 2K8R2 on a separate server and putting TFS there.  Personally I wouldn't want to mess with my WHS functionality.

Comment: I do have MSDN. I don't have the luxury of another server right now. My other machines are not that powerful either. I hope to change that and migrate later. For a single user is the performance load that great?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that only you will be using the TFS system?  Given that you probably don't want to loose things if a hard drive fails, putting the two disks in a mirror is probably best.

With a single user, performance isn't going to be as important as redundancy.

Comment: I should already have redundancy across drives 1 and 2 right?

Comment: If they are setup with a RAID card, or Windows is doing actual mirroring between them then yes.  Without looking at the system I couldn't say for sure as I don't know Home Server well enough.